# View WCF SOAP Message with fiddler

Tags: .net, wcf, fiddler

I have a localhost Client and WCF Webservice and I'm trying to see what the SOAP Message looks like and verify that infact a soap+xml is being used.

I tried using Fiddler and i get weird stuff like this:

```
                <input type="submit" name="cmdGetCapabilities" value="GetCapabilities" id="cmdGetCapabilities" />
                <script type="text/javascript">
LoadRequest('txtGetCapabilitiesRequest', './xml/oseopRequest_GetCapabilities.xml')</script>
                <h5>
                    Response</h5>
                <br />
                <textarea name="txtGetCapabilitiesResponse" id="txtGetCapabilitiesResponse" cols="70" rows="10">Hello test response string</textarea>
            |156|hiddenField|__VIEWSTATE|/wEPDwULLTE4NzQ1MTA5MDIPZBYCAgMPZBYCAgMPZBYCZg9kFgICAw8WAh4JaW5uZXJodG1sBRpIZWxsbyB0ZXN0IHJlc3BvbnNlIHN0cmluZ2RkqYOXbJ/FDnErLs5ws2ZmhyRiXwZoUdF7s5KAUS3NgVU=|72|hiddenField|__EVENTVALIDATION|/wEWAwKEj88XAoyqi+0CAoH3wsYJfbp248BhSjkeWuuXYou1JuSHEFMD2NrnszOSKQq7YZg=|0|asyncPostBackControlIDs|||0|postBackControlIDs|||26|updatePanelIDs||tUpdatePanel1,UpdatePanel1|0|childUpdatePanelIDs|||25|panelsToRefreshIDs||UpdatePanel1,UpdatePanel1|2|asyncPostBackTimeout||90|12|formAction||default.aspx|
```

But fiddler is picking up the client posting back or calling the "click" event and returning data to the browser, there is no session entry that shows the client calling my WCF svc page.

I tried using the TraceViewer which i can see the calls to my web method but no soap envelope.

Anyone know how to view the sending and receiving messages of WCF?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you considered switching on [Message Logging](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730064.aspx)?

Comment: You'll get much better information from WCF logging than you'll ever get from fiddler.

Comment: I was doing it wrong the first time around. This is a lot more straight forward than the blog i read on how to do it. Thanks.